# Angular - Calling API redirected to another module

Tags: angular

I have a component where rest api is called on `ngOnInit`. Calling api redirected to another module but not if I doesn't call the api.

```
export class UserHomeComponent implements OnInit {

    public postData = [];

    constructor(
        private anps: AddNewPostService,
    ) { 

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getPost();
    }


  private getPost() {
    this.anps.getPost().subscribe(
      result => {
        this.postData = result;

        this.postData.forEach(value => {
          value["images"] = "";
          value['postText'] = value['postText'].replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
          let content = "";

          //Bold Data 
          var boldData = [];
          boldData = value['postText'].split("**");

          var num: number = 0;
          let newBoldData = [];
          boldData.forEach(res => {
            if (num % 2 != 0) {
              res = "<b>" + res + "</b>";
            }
            newBoldData.push(res);
            num++;
          });

          newBoldData.forEach(res => {
            content = content + "" + res;
          });

          this.content = content;
          //Bold Data


          //Italic Data
          let italicContent = "";
          var italicData = [];
          italicData = content.split("*");

          var num: number = 0;
          let newItalicData = [];
          italicData.forEach(res => {
            if (num % 2 != 0) {
              res = "<i>" + res + "</i>";
            }
            newItalicData.push(res);
            num++;
          });

          newItalicData.forEach(res => {
            italicContent = italicContent + "" + res;
          });

          this.content = italicContent;
          //Italic Data


          //Image Data
          let imageContent = "";
          var imageData = [];
          imageData = this.content.split("![](");

          var num: number = 0;
          let newImageData = [];
          imageData.forEach(res => {
            let temp = res.split(")");
            let temp1 = [];
            let data = "";
            temp.forEach(res => {
              if (res.includes("https://")) {
                value["images"] = res;
                res = "<a href='" + res + "' target='_blank'/><img style='max-width: 100%;' src='" + res + "' /></a>";
              }
              temp1.push(res);
            })

            temp1.forEach(res => {
              data = data + "" + res;
            })

            newImageData.push(data);
            num++;
          });

          newImageData.forEach(res => {
            imageContent = imageContent + "" + res;
          });

          this.content = imageContent;
          value['postText'] = this.content;
          //Image Data
        })

      },
      error => { console.log(error); }
    )
  }
}
```

Here `UserHomeComponent` is in `UserModule`. My problem is that whenever I put the `getPost()` method on `ngOnInit` method it will be redirect to another module. How can I solve this problem?

`getPost()` method goes like this

```
public getPost() {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl).catch(error => { return this.handleError.handleError(error) });
  }
```

Please help me out!

Comment: Can you upload your AddNewPostService getPost code, it looks like the answer is there

Comment: @benshabatnoam sure

Comment: Not it looks like the answer is in the handle error. maybe there is a navigate logic in there?

Comment: @benshabatnoam - There is no any logic for navigation in handle error

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'redirect to another module'? it is navigating to a another route? where does it redirect to?

Comment: currently I am at `https://localhost:44383/#/isia-user/home` and I am redirected to `https://localhost:44383/#/isia-admin/account/login`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184485/discussion-between-nishan-and-benshabatnoam).

Answer (score -1):

Use only this,

```
public getPost() {
   return this.http.get(this.apiUrl);
}
```

Just try it out.

You should try using promise then and catch rather than subscribe. If subscribed then you should destroy but this has nothing to deal with redirection.